# Saving a specific TensorFlow Checkpoint in time

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

**Is it possible to mark checkpoints not to be deleted?**

A little context:

I am creating a reinforcement learning model and I want to save my best model throughout the training. In order to do that, I am keeping the best score and whenever it is updated saving a checkpoint at that moment in time.

Unfortunately, my best_score checkpoints are getting deleted. I understand that the reason is that TF only keeps the newest 5 checkpoints, and this is fine.

I want just want to keep the most 5 recent checkpoints AND the best checkpoint which might not be in the most recent five. Is there a way to do it without storing all the checkpoints?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the issues posted [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8658/) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9918/), this appears to be a requested feature which is not yet implemented.  You can prevent all checkpoints from being deleted by using `saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=0)`.  If you're doing something big, then to keep this from filling up your disk I'd recommend not starting to save checkpoints until a reasonable number of steps have passed, and not saving unless the current result beats the last saved result by some minimum amount.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/420a7253e034a12ae2208e6ec94d3e4936177a53/research/object_detection/model_lib.py file to be edited for the above solution